# Excel filter groups some dates but not others

Tags: excel-2010

This may be a dumb question with an obvious answer but i can not find or figure out a solution. So I have an excel sheet with 5 tabs, each tab with different data. I've added a filter on the tabs and with some of the date fields it groups by date (you can choose year and month) when you select the drop down. But on others it doesn't.  How can i get it to give this grouping option on all of the dates????

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

my best guess is that all the dates in the other tabs might be stored as text and if so, you can convert them back to the date format by copying `1` and pasting as Multiply (Paste Special > Multiply) to all the dates.